# Элемент формы похожий на строку excel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой элемент формы (c# winforms vs2010 net4.0) может выполнять функции как на рисунке ниже, т.е. это должна быть строка (массив строк) с возможностью в ее ячейках писать текст, выполнять подсчет, выбирать из списков, с кнопкой "удалить" в последнем столбце.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По-моему, строка здесь - это UserControl, кот. включает в себя чекбокс, текстбоксы и т.д.

Comment: DataGridView с колонками разных типов.

Comment: Спасибо! Можете подсказать где можно почитать как считывать и возвращать новые значения в Datagridview "с разными колонками" (как прочитать значения и сохранить их)?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control